# How to save desktop background image to a file in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to save my desktop background to a file and use it in the code. I couldn't find an solution on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to save the wallpaper to a file, because it's already stored in a one.

To find which one, you just have to read the value of `Wallpaper` in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key. Once you know the location of the file, you can do whatever with it.